# Manipulating HTML nodes with java javascript scripting API

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, nashorn, java-scripting-engine

I'm  using the [Java Scripting API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) which is working quite well. Now I have a function where I want to get all `<a>` tags from a String and then add/remove attributes before returning the manipulated String. The problem of course is, that I can't just use `document.getElementsByTagName`. Is there any easy option that comes to your mind without going through regex-hell?

Please note that I'm currently running on Java 7 (with Rhino), planning to update to Java 8 (with Nashorn), so I don't want to use any Rhino specific APIs.

Answer (score 1):

In the book "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns" by Addi Osmani, author mentions 3 alternatives to a similar problem, obviously being getElementById() the fastest.

Excerpt from book:

> Imagine that we have a script where for each DOM element found on page
>   with class "foo," we wish to increment a counter. What's the most
>   efficient way to query for this collection of elements? Well, there
>   are a few different ways this problem could be tackled:
>
> - Select all of the elements in the page and then store references to them. Next, filter this collection and use regular expressions (or
>     another means) to store only those with the class "foo."
> - Use a modern native browser feature such as `querySelectorForAll()` to select all of the elements with the class "foo."
> - Use a netive feature such as `getElementsByClassName()` to similarly...

Another way is, since you're using Nashorn/Rhino, you could use the Java implementation of the Xerces library to manipulate the DOM.

Hope this helps you find out the solution.